# How to get the mean and sum of the random numbers for a date time series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I created a series for all the business days for the year 2016 and then assigned random numbers for each date: 
Created a date time index for the year 2016:

```
df= pd.bdate_range('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
```

output

```
  DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06',
           '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08', '2016-01-11', '2016-01-12',
           '2016-01-13', '2016-01-14',
           ...
           '2016-12-19', '2016-12-20', '2016-12-21', '2016-12-22',
           '2016-12-23', '2016-12-26', '2016-12-27', '2016-12-28',
           '2016-12-29', '2016-12-30'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=261, freq='B')
```

Created index for each columns:

```
    s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(df)), index=df)

  output
2016-01-01    0.430445
2016-01-04   -0.378483
2016-01-05    0.410059
2016-01-06    2.276409
2016-01-07    1.102603
2016-01-08   -0.339722
2016-01-11    0.542110
2016-01-12   -0.898154
 ......
 2016-12-28   -0.952172
 2016-12-29   -1.522073
 2016-12-30   -1.065957
```

I would like to get the sum of index created for each values where I have Tuesday and also I would like to get the mean values of index for each month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem 1: Sum of tuesday values

use [`dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html), and index where `dayofweek == 1` (which represents tuesdays)

```
s[s.index.dayofweek == 1].sum()

# Output:
2.1416224135016124
```

## Problem 2: Mean by month

Use `groupby` with [`pd.Grouper(freq='m')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='m')).mean()

# Output:
2016-01-31    0.072559
2016-02-29    0.009706
2016-03-31    0.118553
2016-04-30   -0.228017
2016-05-31    0.132211
2016-06-30   -0.188015
2016-07-31    0.008239
2016-08-31   -0.181972
2016-09-30    0.554330
2016-10-31   -0.293271
2016-11-30   -0.092587
2016-12-31   -0.268706
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank You @sacul for the help and providing the solution !

Comment: For month mean you can do this too: `s.groupby(s.index.month).mean()`

Comment: @AntonvBR, that would work in this case, but if there are multiple years, it wouldn't (you would lump all Januaries together and so on)

Comment: @sacul Sure but then you can do : `[s.index.year,s.index.month]`, as an alternative.

Comment: Hello Guys, is there any way that I could get the max date for each consecutive 4 months?   For Jan, Feb, Mar, April, it should be '2016-04-30', for Feb, Mar, April, May it should be '2016-05-31' and so on. This would be really helpful.

Comment: You could use freq = ‘4m’ in pd.Grouper. (I think, but I Can’t test, I’m on a phone right now)